# How can I update contents of a text file

Tags: java

My assignment requires me to make a simple mathGame that generates random math problems. The program has to record the amount correct and the amount incorrect in a text file. It also has to update the statistics of an existing file instead of overwrite them.

This is how I am creating each file:

```
try {   
    writer = new FileWriter(userName + " Stats.txt", true);
    outputfile = new PrintWriter (writer);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Here is what is being written to the file:

```
public static void saveStats () {

    outputfile.println();
    outputfile.println("Correct Answers:"+ correct);
    outputfile.println("Incorrect Answers:" + incorrect);

    if (money > 0) {
        outputfile.printf("Earnings: $%.2f", money);
        outputfile.println();
    }
    else {
        float moneyNegative = Math.abs(money);
        outputfile.printf("Earnings: -$%.2f", moneyNegative);
        outputfile.println();
    }
    outputfile.flush();
}
```

Here is a sample output of the text file after quitting the program:

```
Correct Answers:0
Incorrect Answers:1
Earnings: -$0.03
```

correct, incorrect, and money are all global variables and are initialized to 0. If I restart the program, my file will still exist but the values of Correct Answers, Incorrect Answers, and Earnings will be overwritten or a new entry to the file will be added. I just want to update it.

Here is all of my code: https://pastebin.com/1Cmg5Rt8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the original text first, then writing it before you start writing what you need to?

Basically, you take the input from the file you have at the beginning

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("FileName.txt"));
```

Then, you can loop through it and write to the file.

```
while(s.hasNextLine())
{
    outputfile.println(s.nextLine());
}
```

After you have all of your previous file rewritten into the text, you can run the rest of your code and not have the information overwritten.

Also, instead of try-catch you can just throw IOException

Comment: I think your code just copies the old file into the new one. The actual solution would be _retrieving_ the old stats from the old file using the `Scanner.nextInt()` and `Scanner.nextDouble()` (or similar) functions.

Comment: Totally a good way. I didn't know whether or not the user would want to change the variables, but this answer could be changed to allow a person to change the variables found in the file as well.